# Bail-in and equity absorbing losses

Tags: macroeconomics, banking

Below we have a diagram for a bail-in. According to it, as the big company/bank takes a loss in the asset side, the first to absorb those losses, in the liabilities side, is equity. How is this possible? Do the Resolution Authority take the equity from shareholders and sells it on the market? When a company divulges its results, and the market sees the loss, the equity immediately dives (dis)proportionally... Or is this what's called absorbing the loss? Your equity being valued at zero?

[image]

Comment: This is in no way my field of expertise, but they may mean owners' equity, which is the capital theoretically available for distribution to shareholders. This could be in the form of dividends if the firm is publicly owned. I think that specification of equity may help you understand this diagram (that is assuming I didn't misinterpret it myself).